# ruby on rails: rounding variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, rounding, precision

I am a high school teacher with very little programming background and I am trying to make physics problems within a website called "Assistments" which uses Ruby on Rails. I know how to round randomly generated variables and to display them in the problem to the hundredths place using "%.2f" but then when I go to use these variables in the physics equations, the computer does not use the rounded form but rather defaults to the raw value which I do not want. Is there a way to create a variable that is just a permanent rounding of another variable, like, for example:

velocity_hundredths= %v{sprintf("%.2f",velocity_raw)}

Thank you for any help you might give.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't care your background or experience, we just want well-researched and asked questions. SO is like an online reference book and each question is a new article supplying a problem and its fix(es). As such, formatting, grammar and spelling are important. Salutations, valedictions and signatures are undesirable. Please stick to the facts and details as unnecessary information wastes our time and that of others looking for similar solutions. Much of your question is fluff and can be stripped. Try editing it to a concise question, a sentence or two will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `velocity_hundredths = velocity_raw.round(2)`. See [the Float documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-round) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Brian. This is what I put in:                                              magnitude_a = 50-((rand(10000)/10000.00)+rand(100))
magnitude_a_mod = magnitude_a.round(2)

Comment: this is what it returned:                                                                                      "There is an error in the problem's variabilization content. Please tell your teacher that this problem needs to be fixed.: "magnitude_a_mod" cannot be evaluated: (eval):1:in `round': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Comment: What Ruby interpreter and version of Ruby are you using? That code works fine for me using Ruby 2.3 locally as well as REPL (https://repl.it/languages/ruby)...